# Why does my Solidworks Sketch become unsolvable the moment I draw this second line?

Tags: solidworks

So I am trying to draw a 2D planar view of a race track I am making however in solidworks, the moment I draw this second line of a new sketch it becomes unsolvable and I cannot continue. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

I also tried making it into a curve for a corner but after the curve, I tried to add another line and it didn't like it.

EDIT: I changed it into mm from m and it seemed to solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that SOLIDWORKS has a 1km<sup>2</sup> part limit centred around the origin. As such you can't exceed 500m from the origin along any axis.

As you were drawing in MKS units your first line is 400m - within that boundary, so fine. Your second line, while not dimensioned, is clearly >500m long and as such is beyond the allowable limit.